# Read the entire content of file and wrap in single quote

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have a file and I read it as:

```
FILE=$(cat "/path/to/file")
```

This file contains a 4096 character long random string, along with some comments:

```
----- BEGIN KEY ----
2sd763jha8713kjshadi76a...
------ END KEY -----
```

I want to read this whole file as one input, and wrap it in a single quote so that I can post it as JSON. The command above simply returns me the actual content and when I post it, I get a `curl` error of `unknown ---- BEGIN` option.

Comment: `FILE="'$(< /path/to/file)'"` ? (if you're entirely certain it never contains `'` itself.)

Comment: How are you using `$FILE`? Just sticking single quotes around the variable when you use it (assuming you are doing that within double quotes already as you should be) will work.

Comment: @BRPocock Either `\'` OR `"'..'"` not both.

Comment: yeah I did that, and I realized that curl is still throwing me a warning. I want to `POST` it with curl (so `curl --data "{'key' : $FILE}" ...`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not wrap arbitrary text in single quotes to make it JSON or JSON safe.

Use a JSON tool instead:

```
$ jq -s -R . file
"----- BEGIN KEY ----\n2sd763jha8713kjshadi76a...\n------ END KEY -----\n"
```

Comment: suggesting `jq` is perfect here!